# How do I detect whether the user is printing to PDF?

Tags: delphi, pdf

I'm using Delphi 7 and want to know if the file is printing to a PDF device so I can do some special processing. This is what I have to get it to work.

```
// If the printer is a PDF type it will ask for the file name here.
Printer.BeginDoc;
// The next line returns the file extension of the original file name and 
// not the extension of the file being printed to.
Extension := AnsiUpperCase(ExtractFileExt(Printer.Title));
// I've added this line to get it to work but want to be able 
// just check if the current child is being printed to a pdf device.
if CustomPrintDialog.ActivePrinter.Caption = 'Adobe PDF' then
```

Comment: You cannot possibly know whether or not the ultimate destination is PDF. Ask the user for the information. The user can know.

Comment: If I were you, I'd reconsider whether that "special processing" is really necessary, or whether it really needs to be special. When I print to PDF, I expect the result to be the same as if I'd printed it to paper. That's what's so attractive about PDF. If the results differ, then I'd lose trust in the application. And why PDF, specifically? I've sometimes printed to Postscript, and then generated a PDF from that. Would your "special processing" still apply in that case? What about printing to XPS? I invite you to post a new question describing the underlying problem you're seeking to solve.

Comment: The program prints to devices that have continuous paper with no margins. The drawing I am doing may be 200" or longer. If I print that to a PDF and a client goes to print it they rarely have a continuous printer. So, when printing to a PDF we want to print to a forced page size of 8.25" x 10.5" so that when the item prints on most printers it will fit. The drawing going to the printer is scaled so scaling to the printer is not an option.

Comment: Isn't that something you can get from the supported paper sizes?

Comment: No, because when you query a PDF "printer" it says the paper size is 8.5 x 11. Not many printers can actually print on that size piece of paper. Also, I can't have the client scale to print the 8.5x11 document as that will throw the scaling of the document off. There is almost always a left, top, and bottom margins where it is impossible for most printers to print.

Comment: Let me try another explanation. My program draws a scaled image to many different types of printers. It queries the actual drawing areas and draws the image using the physical limits of the printer. So, on a typical 8.5x11" piece of paper it will print in an area typically from 10.8" to 10.5" depending on the printer. However, when I print it to a PDF file I have no way of knowing what type of printer the client will use. When I query the PDF printer for a letter size piece of paper it will return 11" high. Well, I know the client will probably not be able to print that size so I want to force

Comment: the page size to be 10.5" tall with a top and bottom margin of 0.25". This way when the client prints it the PDF document it will appear exactly like document with nothing cut off the top or bottom. I hope this helps explain why I need to treat a PDF document different than a document going directly to a printer.